# How to list all AD Users and AD Computers together?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to export all AD Users with their hostname with PowerShell.

I can type:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name, ipv4address, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion -SearchBase "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" -Server "my.domain.com" | Format-Table Name, OperatingSystem, ipv4*
```

The result of this will give me all of the hostnames, OS and IP addresses in my Domain.

But how do I add AD users (last logged on user) to this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get all the list of users** present in AD, you can use:

> Get-ADUser -filter *

**For getting the last logon** , you can use the below function:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName)
{
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $time = 0
  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  { 
    $hostname = $dc.HostName
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
    {
      $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
  }
  $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
  Write-Host $username "last logged on at:" $dt }

# Call the function with parameter
Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName TestUser01
```

Note: You can use different filters also for it.

Reference Link: [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378867(v=ws.10).aspx)

**In your case**, I can see already you are fetching all the details except the last logon. Use the above function , store the result in an *arraylist* and just add it to your *final object*. That should give your desired output along with the *Get-AdComputer* which is already you are using.

Unfortunately, Active Directory does not capture the information for the each corresponding hostname mapped with User logged in system. A user can log in from any of the computers joined in the domain.

You can try enabling *security audit* then go to each *DC in your domain*, look at the security log and see where that user logged in from.

But I don't think that will be captured in a specific way. They might use something in generic for all users.
(I am not sure if you are looking for the mapping also thats why I wrote)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

to find the last logged in user on a server you can utilize:

```
quser /server:$server | select -Last 1 | %{($_.trim() -split "\s+")[0]}
```

or you can use powershell remoting to the destination server ,inside that scriptblock you can give:

```
quser | select -Last 1 | %{($_.trim() -split "\s+")[0]}
```